# rails where to put controller code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a select box on a new Workorder form so the user can select the Location.

This is the form input field:

```
 <%= f.select :location_id, @loctree %>
```

I have some controller code that defines what @loctree should return.

But, I'm confused on where to put that code.  Does it go into the Workorders_controller.rb in the "def new" area?  Or does it go somewhere in the Locations_controller.rb?

Thbanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code you posted handles the new action for Workorders, then it should be in the `new` method in `Workorders_controller`. This method will be run before your template, and any member variables set there will be available for use in your template.